# Load testing with a TransactionManager using JMeter or Gatling

Tags: jmeter, transactions, load-testing, gatling

How to add a TransactionManager to a JMeter test?

I'm attempting to replicate the production load against various JMS broker configurations with JMeter (or Gatling).

The production app that I want to simulate uses both JMS persistence and a JMS TransactionManager (org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager).

JMeter has a simple tickbox for persistence, but I cannot find how to inject a TransactionManager.

It is a common statement in JMS broker documentation that transactions have negligible impact on JMS, however a) I need to provide evidence and not just unverified statements, and b) the statements appear to relate to performance whilst I am very interested in the impact on IOPS and disk usage.

I don't believe that JMeter "Transaction Controller" is relevant for my purposes.

If I have not provided some information that you think is important, then please assume that I don't realise why it is important.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response as it saves me wasting any more time trying to find a solution.

I'll update the question to make it clear that I am trying to test the behaviour of the broker, and not the application, under load.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add the "TransactionManager" either to JMeter or to Gatling test.

However you don't need to "add" it at all, if your "production" app uses "TransactionManager" it doesn't mean that you have to use it for testing.

All you need to do is to replicate the JMS messages coming to your "production app" as close as possible, my expectation is that you need to send them to some form of [MQ broker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker) and let your "production app" to ingest these messages. If your "production app" will be able to process the messages at the velocity JMeter (or whatever) sends them - it's good to go and vice versa.

References:

- [Building a JMS Topic Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html)
- [Building a JMS Point-to-Point Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-point-to-point-test-plan.html)
- [IBM MQ Tutorial: Learn How to Testing With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-tutorial)